# Implementing LRU cache in Rails/PostgreSQL app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, caching

I have an appointment-scheduling app where the vast majority of appointment data is "water under the bridge". For any given calendar page, maybe 5% of the appointments on that page are fresh; the rest are old and unlikely to ever be changed.

The problem is that each page can have tons of appointments, and loading all those appointments (even with eager loading) is slow. I want to do some caching to speed things up, but I don't want to invalidate the entire cache every time someone creates an appointment, because the user sees the calendar page after every appointment creation, so it seems that invalidating the whole cache at that point would defeat the whole purpose of caching.

My understanding is that what I want is an [LRU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used). How might I implement this in a Rails/PostgreSQL cache? Should it be done at the application level or database level? Is an LRU cache even the right thing?

Comment: I'd look at using `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` with a payload to signal the cache for selective invalidation. The cache could be Memcached, Redis, or something more ActiveRecord/Rails specific.

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that your ORM may be generating lots of little queries.  The first thing to look at doing is consolidating your data statements and dropping to SQL as appropriate to grab the set of interesting appointments.  From there you can make things very fast using PostgreSQL indexes.  Note that PostgreSQL allows you to create partial indexes as well as full ones, which allows you to index pieces of your table one at a time.

However if that doesn't work, then one option is to use LISTEN and NOTIFY to invalidate specific cache entries and force their rebuild.  However you have some significant challenges here and so it is not where I would start.  Keep in mind PostgreSQL does a fair bit of LRU caching itself and so the more you can work on that, and optimizing your database, the less you have to worry about the rest.